# Yammer search endpoint user access

Tags: rest, sdk, yammer

I'm working on creating an application for a client that has to search Yammer for a term specified by a user. I'm using the [Yammer JavaScript SDK](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/js-sdk) to authenticate the user's login to acquire the access token which I then use to query the [search REST API](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/searchjson).

This is all working great, but I need to know about the user access rights using the SDK and REST API. Will the search endpoint restrict the search results to the groups and files that a user has access to? Or does the endpoint return everything that matches the search term regardless of the user's access to it?

Unfortunately I only have the one user account on the client's Yammer network to test with and can't really investigate the issue properly.

Any feedback will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return only what that user has access too
ie. If they can not see a hidden private group they would not be able to search for it

Try to think of the Javascript SDK emulating them logged into yammer.com

Comment: Thanks Matthew! It's quite obvious actually, but try convincing a non-technical client that's the case without having any supporting or corroborating documentation...

Comment: I do find the API documentation to be very poor. It is also missing requests that are very useful but not listed on their website